# fast way of summing row entries in diagonal position of matrix in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Hi I am trying to solve below equation where `A` is a sparse matrix and `ptotal` is an array of numbers. I have to sum all the entries in a row at diagonal position.

```
A[ptotal, ptotal] = -sum(A[ptotal, :])
```

The code seems to give right answer but since my ptotal array is long almost (100000 entries), it is computationally not efficient. Is there any fast method to solve this problem.

Comment: What's with the `c++` tag?  `sparse` - a numpy array with lots of 0's or a `scipy.sparse` matrix?  `ptotal` - are the values unique, or are there duplicates?  A small test case might help.

Comment: Its a `scipy.sparse` matrix. `ptotal` is an array of values starting from 0 to 100000. All values are unique there are no duplicates. @hpaulj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a dense array version:

```
In [87]: A = np.arange(36).reshape(6,6)
In [88]: ptotal = np.arange(6)
```

Assuming `ptotal` is all the row indices, it can be replace with a `sum` method call:

```
In [89]: sum(A[ptotal,:])
Out[89]: array([ 90,  96, 102, 108, 114, 120])
In [90]: A.sum(axis=0)
Out[90]: array([ 90,  96, 102, 108, 114, 120])
```

We can make an array with those values on the diagonal:

```
In [92]: np.diagflat(A.sum(axis=0))
Out[92]: 
array([[ 90,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,  96,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 102,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, 108,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 114,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 120]])
```

Add it to the original array - and the result is a 'zero-sum' array:

```
In [93]: A -= np.diagflat(A.sum(axis=0))
In [94]: A
Out[94]: 
array([[-90,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
       [  6, -89,   8,   9,  10,  11],
       [ 12,  13, -88,  15,  16,  17],
       [ 18,  19,  20, -87,  22,  23],
       [ 24,  25,  26,  27, -86,  29],
       [ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34, -85]])
In [95]: A.sum(axis=0)
Out[95]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

We could do the same with sparse

```
In [99]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(36).reshape(6,6))
In [100]: M
Out[100]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 35 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [101]: M.sum(axis=0)
Out[101]: matrix([[ 90,  96, 102, 108, 114, 120]], dtype=int32)
```

A sparse diagonal matrix:

```
In [104]: sparse.dia_matrix((M.sum(axis=0),0),M.shape)
Out[104]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 6 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
In [105]: _.A
Out[105]: 
array([[ 90,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,  96,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 102,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, 108,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 114,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 120]], dtype=int32)
```

Take the difference, getting a new matrix:

```
In [106]: M-sparse.dia_matrix((M.sum(axis=0),0),M.shape)
Out[106]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 36 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [107]: _.A
Out[107]: 
array([[-90,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
       [  6, -89,   8,   9,  10,  11],
       [ 12,  13, -88,  15,  16,  17],
       [ 18,  19,  20, -87,  22,  23],
       [ 24,  25,  26,  27, -86,  29],
       [ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34, -85]], dtype=int32)
```

There is also a `setdiag` method

```
In [117]: M.setdiag(-M.sum(axis=0).A1)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:774: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
In [118]: M.A
Out[118]: 
array([[ -90,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5],
       [   6,  -96,    8,    9,   10,   11],
       [  12,   13, -102,   15,   16,   17],
       [  18,   19,   20, -108,   22,   23],
       [  24,   25,   26,   27, -114,   29],
       [  30,   31,   32,   33,   34, -120]], dtype=int32)
```

`Out[101]` is a 2d matrix; `.A1` turns it into a 1d array which `setdiag` can use.

The sparse efficiency warning is aimed more at iterative use than a one time application like this.  Still, looking at the `setdiag` code, I suspect the first approach is faster.  But we really need to do time tests.

Comment: M-sparse.dia_matrix((M.sum(axis=0),0),M.shape) approach has decreased time from 38 sec to 1.2 sec when len(ptotal)=27000. So there is a significant improvement in time. Thank you very much @hpaulj.